# how to use req.params.put in test code for testing htttpGet

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, rest

i have wrapper class like below

```
public class wrapper_class {
    public class requestWrapper { 
        string userName; 
        string LastName,
        string Phone; 

        public (Map params) { 
            this.userName= string.valueOf(params.get('userName')); 
            this.LastName= string.valueOf(params.get('LastName')); 
            this.Phone= string.valueOf(params.get('Phone')); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

in httpGet i am using like

```
RestRequest r = RestContext.request;
wrapper_class.requestWrapper objectReq = new wrapper_class.requestWrapper(r.params);
```

how can i implement test code for above wrapper class + httpGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you can construct a `RestRequest` instance and set it in the static field of the `RestContext` and the code you are testing can then pick the values back out:

```
RestRequest r = new RestRequest();
r.params.put('userName', 'fake-user-name');
r.params.put('LastName', 'fake-last-name');
r.params.put('Phine', 'fake-phone');
RestContext.request = r;

// Invoke static HTTP method
```

**PS**

In response to your comment you could add this method to the wrapper:

```
public class wrapper_class {
    public class requestWrapper { 
        string userName; 
        string LastName,
        string Phone; 

        public (Map params) { 
            this.userName= string.valueOf(params.get('userName')); 
            this.LastName= string.valueOf(params.get('LastName')); 
            this.Phone= string.valueOf(params.get('Phone')); 
        }

        @TestVisible
        private void transferToRequest(RestRequest r ) {
            r.params.put('userName', userName);
            r.params.put('LastName', LastName);
            r.params.put('Phine', phone);
        }
    } 
}
```

and then change the test to:

```
wrapper_class w = new wrapper_class(...);
RestRequest r = new RestRequest();
w.transferToRequest(r);
RestContext.request = r;

// Invoke static HTTP method
```

Comment: thanks keith ...how can we include wrapper class in it here

Comment: @ApexCode Not exactly sure what you are looking for but see the PS I added.